# Pass in state variable value, instead of variable in react lambda function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I have this react component:

```
export const ClientChannelsList = (props) => {
  const [theDate, setTheDate] = useState(null);
  const [theFilter, setTheFilter] = useState({
    collectionQuery: c => c.where('created_stripe', '>=', 1611700523)
  });


  function handleDateChanged(date) {
    setTheDate(date.getTime()/1000);
    setTheFilter({
      collectionQuery: c => c.where('created_stripe', '>=', theDate)
    });

  }
  return (
    <List exporter={exporter} filter={theFilter} {...props} filters={filters} actions={<TheActions/>}>
      <>
        <Datagrid>
          <TextField label="Channel Id" source="ChannelId"/>
          <TextField label="Name" source="Name"/>
          <TextField label="Email" source="EmailAddress"/>
          <TextField label="Subscription Status" source="SubscriptionStatus"/>
          <TextField label="Has Subscription" source="HasSubscription"/>
          <TextField label="Host Channel Id" source="HostChannelId"/>
          <TextField source="HostChannelName"/>
          <DeleteButton label="" redirect={false}/>
        </Datagrid>
        <DatePicker selected={theDate*1000} onChange={(date) => handleDateChanged(date)}/>
      </>
    </List>
  )
};
```

This component uses the [react-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-admin) module

All I am trying to do is to add a custom filter by passing `theFilter` to the `filter` prop of the `List` component.
The issue thats happening is that whenever a date is set using DatePicker, the collection query gets passed on as `c=>c.where('created_stripe', '>=', theDate)`, whereas I would want it to take in the value of `theDate` in this function something like `collectionQuery: c=>c.where('created_stripe','>=', 165343454)`.

So how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use useEffect for that code to run only once?

```
export const ClientChannelsList = (props) => {
  const [theDate, setTheDate] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  const [theFilter, setTheFilter] = useState({
    collectionQuery: c => c.where('created_stripe', '>=', 1611700523)
  });
})


  function handleDateChanged(date) {
    setTheDate(date.getTime()/1000);
    setTheFilter({
      collectionQuery: c => c.where('created_stripe', '>=', theDate)
    });

  }
  return (
    <List exporter={exporter} filter={theFilter} {...props} filters={filters} actions={<TheActions/>}>
      <>
        <Datagrid>
          <TextField label="Channel Id" source="ChannelId"/>
          <TextField label="Name" source="Name"/>
          <TextField label="Email" source="EmailAddress"/>
          <TextField label="Subscription Status" source="SubscriptionStatus"/>
          <TextField label="Has Subscription" source="HasSubscription"/>
          <TextField label="Host Channel Id" source="HostChannelId"/>
          <TextField source="HostChannelName"/>
          <DeleteButton label="" redirect={false}/>
        </Datagrid>
        <DatePicker selected={theDate*1000} onChange={(date) => handleDateChanged(date)}/>
      </>
    </List>
  )
};
```

Comment: how is this a solution? This won't even compile!

Comment: The idea is to use useEffect to isolate that part of code wich is getting runned whenever yur are updating the state

Comment: your code won't work because you can't use `useState` in a callback(useEffect). Any react hook can only be used in a functional component(And not in any other place/callback)